# Represent a list of items in input CSV for H2O

Tags: machine-learning, h2o, sparkling-water

How do I represent a set/list of items in the input data (data frame) for H2O?

I'm using sparkling water 1.6.5 with H2O Flow.
My input data (columns in the CSV file) look like this:

```
age: numeric
gender: enum
hobbies: ?
sports: ?
```

hobbies and sports are lists/sets with a limited number of possible entries (~20 each). H2O does not seem to have a suitable data type for this. How do I export these into a CSV file that can be processed by H2O Flow?

Comment: No idea about h2o, but machine learning has a concept called `one hot encoding`. You can simply make every possible entry in your hobby and sports list a "csv column" itself that is binary like your gender attribute.

Comment: Sounds like a valid option, thanks. However, I hope there is an easier / more maintainable way than doing this manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were just recording their main hobby, or main sport, then it would be a single enum column, e.g. hobbies, with 20 levels. You would simply write it as a string field in your csv file, and H2O would read it.

But I think what you are after is where each person has 0+ choices from 20 hobbies? In that case you need to have 20 columns in your csv file, one per hobby; each will be a 2-value enum. It doesn't matter what the two values are: Y/N, T/F, Y/blank, hobby-name/blank, etc. Your csv file might look this:

```
name,gender,football?,running?,data mining?,sleeping?
Tom,M,Y,,,Y
Dick,M,,,Y,
Suzy,F,,Y,Y,
```

Tom likes football and sleeping, Dick lives for data mining and nothing else, and Suzy is into running and data mining.

By the way, if using `deeplearning` then it will end up with the same network configuration: a single 20-level enum input will be converted into 20 binary inputs nodes.

Comment: Thx. How do I write this into my CSV? I tried to separate the hobbies with commas (e.g. "singing,painting") but that didn't work. I don't have to use a CSV file if there is a better format.

Comment: Sorry, @MarkusKramer, I'd missed the point of your question. Just updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. so the "one hot encoding" method suggested by Thomas is the answer for H2O as well